# scons: Out of memory in compiler while using ghs compiler

Tags: scons

I have used the ghs compiler with scons.
The following error occurred while compiling the test.c file, which is about 5M in size.

As far as I'm aware, the following error is not a compiler error since the compiler is marked 'fatal error #4: out of memory'

So, I think it's the error that scons throws, but I don't know why this error occur.

---

```
"Generated/bt_out/src/test.c", line 2015: warning #550-D: variable
          "Dw_Gal_Local_PC_10_C_C_Status_1" was set but never
          used
  static VAR(ReturnT, RTE_VINIT) R_Gus_Local_PC_1_4_C_ = ATE__OK;

Out of memory in compiler

scons: *** [Debug\Generated/bt_out/src/test.o] Error 1
```

---

Comment: I think you can configure scons to show the command line used to invoke the compiler. When you run the compiler with that command-line does it also crash with Out-Of-Memory (OOM) error?

Comment: scons is merely acting as a dispatcher - the error message you're seeing (`scons: ***`) is just it reporting the failure report (a non-zero exit code) it got from the command it fired off to build `test.o`.

Comment: Were you building in parallel ? `scons -j SOME_NUMBER_NOT_1`

Comment: Thank you all. This error is the compiler error. I'm going to ask of the ghs.

Comment: I had somehow got my build environment to build in parallel.  It was sending `-parallel 6` to the `gbuild` command line, which was wrong, should have said `-parallel=6`.  This caused `gbuild` to spawn as many processes as it could and all my memory was eaten up.  Wish I remembered what I did to get it that way.